# Programmatically set TextView with Scrollbar on the top

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with *TextView* that has *ScrollBar*. I know that in order to create scrollbar on the textview, I need to enable this on the xml:

```
android:scrollbar="vertical"
```

and in the *code.java*, I set like this:

```
tvChapterDesc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Then, now user could scroll the TextView, if it is more than the defined number of lines. (say maxlines = 5).

However, I have a *Button* where if it is clicked, it is supposed to scrolled the textview to the top, can I do this? How? For example that the textview has 1000 lines, and there is a button "top". if user click button "top", it will be scrolled to the top immediately, so user can start reading to the beginning of the textview again. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) function on the textView.